# Is it possible to register an UDF that has generic return type in Scala

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions

Basically what i'm trying to do is make my own IF function but with generic return types

I'm trying to register this function so i can use it with a DataFrame

```
def myfunc[A] (cond : Boolean, condMet : A, condNotMet : A): A = {
  if(cond)
    return condMet;
  else
    return condNotMet;

}
val apply_func = udf(myfunc _);
val xp = h.withColumn("myUDF", apply_func('values0,"met",false).show
```

But I got this error

```
<console>:100: error: type mismatch;
found   : (Boolean, Nothing, Nothing) => Nothing
required: (Boolean, A2, A3) => RT
       val apply_func = udf(myfunc _);
```

I want to know if I can actually register that function or if another function than does the same already exists, or maybe it's just not possible.

I will mostly be sending String, Boolean, Numbers as condMet and condNotMet.

Comment: On your usage of `return`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560463/return-in-scala/12560532

Comment: In your example, what should be the type of the new column?

Comment: I don't have a set type, it depends on the specific case. That's why I am struggling with it

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's possible with UDFs, but you can drop down to the RDD level. For example:

```
def myfunc[A] (cond : Boolean, condMet : A, condNotMet : A): A = {
  if(cond)
    return condMet
  else
    return condNotMet
}

val test = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3))
val res = test.map(r => myfunc(r == 1, 1, "B").getClass)
```

Now res has an Array of classes where you can also see their types. Take a look as follows:

```
res.take(3)
res: Array[Class[_]] = Array(class java.lang.Integer, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String)
```

Comment: Then you can go back to a DataFrame using .toDF()

Answer (score 0):

Columns in a DataFrame must have a certain type.

Although I don't quite get your example, you could do something like this:

```
val df=sc.parallelize(Seq(0,1,2)).toDF("mycol")

val xp = df.withColumn("myNewCol",
      when($"mycol" === lit(1), lit("met")).otherwise(lit(999))
    )
```

The new column is then automatically created as a column of type string.

using your udf, you would have to do this:

```
def myfunc[A] (cond : Boolean, condMet : A, condNotMet : A): A = {
  if(cond)
    return condMet
  else
    return condNotMet

}
val apply_func = udf(myfunc[String] _)
val xp = df.withColumn("myUDF", apply_func($"myNewCol"===1,lit("met"),lit(999)))
```