# how to convert java method return to scala?

Tags: scala

how to convert this java code to scala ? Scala doesn't prefer 'return', then scala has a better version ?

```
public void myMethod(String name){
  if(s==null) return;
  //other logic and many lines ....
}
```

Comment: There nothing wrong with that.  `return` is useful for exiting early from a guard condition.  If you want to avoid it, just put the rest of your method into the `else` part of that if.  However, if you want to write "idiomatic" scala.  Return a value, don't write void methods (`Unit` in Scala).  Keep your methods and functions short as well, doing so makes them more reusable and reduces the need for early returns.

Comment: I agree with you. so many lines put into an else , it is hard to read.

Comment: Shouldn't be any harder to read than what you already have.  I don't see much different between `if (condition) return; //lots of code` and `if (condition) else{ //lots of code}` from a readability perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do this in two steps:

```
def myMethod(name: String): Unit =
  if(name == null) () else{
    //rest of code that works via side-effect
  }
```

The `()` denotes an instance of `Unit`.

That's ok but there's something even better! This take advantage that the `Option` constructor has special `null` handling, e.g. `Option(null) == None`.

```
def myMethod(name: Option[String]): Unit = name.foreach{
  //rest of code that works via side-effect
}
```

Wherein if you might have something which could be `null` you will make sure that the type system specifies that the variable might or might not contain a value (yes, Java now has `Optional` too and for similar reasons!)

Answer (score 0):

Or refactor the code in this way:

```
def myMethod(name: String) = {
  if (name != null) {
  //other logic and many lines ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you don't need to use the **return** keyword. The return is Scala is pretty much explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560463/return-in-scala) pretty much but I'd like to point out a few things.

#### Expressions vs. Statements

Most constructs in Java are statements which means they only executed, *not* evaluated. This is quite important because in Scala most of these constructs are expressions. Let's see how this works on an if-construct.

```java
// Initialize i to 1 if some condition is true otherwise to 0
int i;
if (someCondition) i = 1;
else i = 0;
```

Assuming we'd like to initialize i in one step (maybe we'd like making it final) we need to use a ternary operator:

```java
final int i = someCondition ? 1 : 0;
```

This works because the right hand side is actually an expression. Now let's write this in Scala:

```scala
val i = if (someCondition) 1 else 0
```

This is a conditional expression.

#### Functions

A good thing to keep in mind about functions is that the *return value of a function* is *equal to the result of its last expression*. This being you can define the if-expression as the latest in your function and thus its result will be returned. Applying this to your code leaves us with:

```scala
def myMethod(name: String): Int = {
  if (s == null) -1
  else { ... }
}
```

I've updated your method to return an `Int` in this case for the sake of argument. You probably need to replace it with something more meaningful. On the else branch you'd also need to return an `Int` in this case. Anyway I hope this clears your request.

As a closing note [this](https://github.com/databricks/scala-style-guide#return) is a nice guide explaining why you should avoid using `return`. Personally I haven't used it at all even though there are some examples there.