# function not indicate return type - Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to scala. In tutorial I saw the way to define a function is

```
def functionName ([list of parameters]) : [return type] = {...}
```

But in other's code I saw following example that function did not indicate return type. Why is this?

```
  def parseLine(line:String) = {
    val fields = line.split(",")
    val stationID = fields(0)
    val entryType = fields(2)
    val temperature = fields(3).toFloat * 0.1f * (9.0f / 5.0f) + 32.0f
    (stationID, entryType, temperature)
  }
```

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/local-type-inference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no return type the last expression is return value.

example,

```
scala> def doSomething = "i will be returned"
doSomething: String
```

you can see in above example though there's no return type mentioned, it will take `String` as return type.

Also if the method is returning based on conditions, scalac will figure itself out the return type.

```
scala> def doSomething = if(1 == 1) "i will be returned" else 2
doSomething: Any

scala> doSomething
res10: Any = i will be returned
```

Also read - [Return in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560463/return-in-scala)