# there were compilation error scala spark expected class or object definition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i want to run this program i am new to scala spark I've got the "there were compilation error"
any one can help me with this?

enter code here

```
package main.scala.com.matthewrathbone.spark
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.collection.Map

class ExampleJob(sc: SparkContext) {
  // reads data from text files and computes the results. This is what you test
  def run(t: String, u: String) : RDD[(String, String)] = {
    val transactions = sc.textFile(t)
    val newTransactionsPair = transactions.map{t =>                
        val p = t.split(" ")
        (p(2).toInt, p(1).toInt)
    }

val users = sc.textFile(u)
val newUsersPair = users.map{t =>                
    val p = t.split(" ")
    (p(0).toInt, p(3))
}

val result = processData(newTransactionsPair, newUsersPair)
return sc.parallelize(result.toSeq).map(t => (t._1.toString, t._2.toString))


 } 

  def processData (t: RDD[(Int, Int)], u: RDD[(Int, String)]) : Map[Int,Long] = {
    var jn = t.leftOuterJoin(u).values.distinct
    return jn.countByKey
  }
}

object ExampleJob {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
   val transactionsIn = Resource.fromFile("/home/ali/Desktop/main/scala/com/matthewrathbone/spark/transactions.txt")
    val usersIn = Resource.fromFile("/home/ali/Desktop/main/scala/com/matthewrathbone/spark/users.txt") 

//val transactionsIn = args(1)
  //  val usersIn = args(0)
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJoins").setMaster("local")
    val context = new SparkContext(conf)
    val job = new ExampleJob(context)
    val results = job.run(transactionsIn, usersIn)
    //val output = args(2)
val output = Resource.fromFile("/home/ali/Desktop/main/scala/com/matthewrathbone/spark/out.txt")
    results.saveAsTextFile(output)
    context.stop()
  }
}
```

i was try that whit the input from args but the error was just the same.
this code does some operation on tow text file in spark-shell 
i have also some times get error of first line of package definition.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem, 
there was mismatch in parameters of-course but i changed it to string and the problem not solved, after that i used sbt for packaging and compiling, sbt added the libraries automatically and the program runs correctly, thank you for answers

Answer (score 1):

Your `run` method takes 2 parameters which are 2 String `(t: String, u: String)` but in your `main` method, you are invoking it with 2 `Resource`. You want to make change the `transactionsIn` and `usersIn` as String, like this:

```
val transactionsIn = "/home/ali/Desktop/main/scala/com/matthewrathbone/spark/transactions.txt"
val usersIn = "/home/ali/Desktop/main/scala/com/matthewrathbone/spark/users.txt" 
...//context initialization
val results = job.run(transactionsIn, usersIn)
```

I'm also new to Scala, but I don't think you should use `return` in the code, see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560463/return-in-scala).

Comment: i did this also before but the exception was the same, any suggestion?

Comment: Your question is about compilation but you said you got exception. What exactly is the exception that you got? I tested with dummy transactions.txt and users.txt and it seems to work fine.

Comment: The `output` also has to be a string, not a `Resource`