# What does type mismatch in scala mean and how do I fix it here?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to solve this problem.

In a package named "`lecture`" create an `object` named "`FirstObject`"
with a method named "`computeShippingCost`" that takes a `Double`
representing the weight of a package as a parameter and returns a
`Double` representing the shipping cost of the package

• The shipping cost is `($)5 + 0.25` for each pound over 30

• Every package weighing 30 pounds or less will cost 5 to ship

• A package weighing 31 pounds cost 5.25 to ship

• A package weighing 40 pounds cost 7.50 to ship

Here's my scala code so far:

```
package lecture

object FirstObject {
  def computeShippingCost(weightOfpackage: Double): Double = {
    val shippingCost = 5
    if (weightOfpackage <= 30){
      return shippingCost
    }
    if (weightOfpackage >30){
      return (shippingCost) + (weightOfpackage - 30) * (.25)
    }

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(computeShippingCost(25.0)) // expect 5.0
  }
}
```

I keep receiving an error message saying

```
type: Mismatch, found:Unit, required: Double.
```

What does that mean in the context of the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

In `computeShippingCost` there is a case that is not handled - and this returns `Unit`. In ***Scala*** every `if` needs to have an `else`. So your other case is if the last `if` does not match.

So what is needed is that you handle every possible case. And each of them must return a `Double`.

The correct code in ***Scala*** looks like:

```
def computeShippingCost(weightOfpackage: Double): Double = {
    val shippingCost = 5
    if (weightOfpackage <= 30){
      shippingCost
    } else {
      shippingCost + (weightOfpackage - 30) * 0.25
    } 
  }
```

By the way no `return` needed in ***Scala***.

Check out this explanation: [Return in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12560532/2750966)

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't know return doesn't exist in scala. Which case was not being handled that returned unit in the previous code?

Comment: Oh I just realized I had a if after another if my bad

Comment: ok I added this in my answer and I added a link to some further reading.

Comment: @indentation `return` does exist, but it's preferred to avoid it.

Comment: @indentation if this fixed your problem please accept and upvote the answer or add a comment what is missing.