# Scala: return datatype Array([Int, Double])

Tags: arrays, scala, tuples

I have for example a function that requires to return data type `Array([Int, Double])` like this:

```
def foo(x: Int, y:Double): Array[(Int, Double)] = {
   return x,y
}
```

How can I return `x,y` that match the required datatype `Array[(Int, Double)]`? I try `return Array(x,y)` but got type mismatch errors:

```
type mismatch; found : Int required: (Int, Double)
type mismatch; found : Double required: (Int, Double)
```

Comment: Read the basics about the Scala language features! It helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
def foo(x: Int, y:Double): Array[(Int, Double)]  = {
  Array((x,y))
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/b4m3TdkUQRW20SubJxUYxw/2).

Comment: Hi, I don't understand where is the "return" part?

Comment: @HaAnTran. TL;DR: It's not needed in Scala. For more information please read [Return in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12560463/2359227)