# When to use keyword return in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, return, sbt

I learned early on that there is no reason to use the `return` keyword in Scala (as far as I'm aware). That being said I found an example where simply changing adding the `return` keyword made my function work, where it previously didn't.

The code in question comes from [my solution](https://github.com/ZachElkins/Advent-Of-Code-2020/tree/main/day07) to the [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com) day 7 challenge.

```
def containsShinyGoldBag(bagContents: Map[String, List[String]], currentBag: String): Boolean = {
    val contents = bagContents(currentBag)

    if (bagContents(currentBag).contains("shiny gold") ) {
        // Base Case: Bag Found in list of bags
        true
    } else if (contents == List.empty){
        // Base Case: Dead End
        false
    } else {
        // Continue searching down list

        // Ideal solution ( gives same result as the working solution without return keyword )
        // for (b <- contents) containsShinyGoldBag(bagContents, b)

        // Working solution
        for (b <- contents) {
            if (containsShinyGoldBag(bagContents, b)) {
                println(s"Found one! $b inside a $currentBag")
                return true // <--- culprit
            }
            else false
        }
        false
    }
}

// In the main function

var count = 0
for (bag <- bagContents.keys) {
    if (containsShinyGoldBag(bagContents, bag)) {
        count = count + 1
    }
}
println(s"There are $count way to bring a shiny gold bag!")
```

When I run the code without `return` I end up with `count = 7`, which is the number of bags directly containing a shiny gold bag, rather than the correct number which counts bags that contain a shiny gold bag somewhere inside of one of their other bags down the line.

Comment: Technically speaking you never ever need it, every algorithm that may need it can be rewriten in a way or another that doesn't need it. - Practically speaking, sometimes the alternative is harder to understand or more inefficient so why not using it? - Personally speaking, I have never found a good reason for using it _(in my own code)_ since it is usually common on more imperative code and mine is usually more functional and things like **cats** provide good alternatives for when you may need it using only the stdlib _(`traverse` being the most common example)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I understand that it isn't necessary. I'm just asking what about this specific example makes adding `return` give a different result

Comment: Yeah that is exactly the reason why it is avoided. Because it can mean different things. Sometimes it may mean what you want it to mean _(like this case)_ Sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: The reason why you need it in this case is because you are using an imperative `foreach` which doesn't return any value as most other Scala expressions.

Comment: [return in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12560463/2359227)

Comment: The thing about `return` is that it doesn't always work like `return` in, say, Java - non-local returns (from within lambdas and for loops) use an exception to break out and are messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function returns the value of the last expression it evaluates; in your case that will be one of:

1. `true` after `if (bagContents(currentBag).contains("shiny gold") )`;
2. `false` after `else if (contents == List.empty)`;
3. the last `false`.

`true` is not in such a position, so you need `return` to, well, make the function return it. Otherwise it's evaluated and ignored because you don't do anything with it. So is `else false` in the same `for`, actually, it can be removed without changing the meaning.

The alternative to avoid `return` here is

```
contents.exists(b => containsShinyGoldBag(bagContents, b))
```