# Check if two types are equivalent through reflection in scala

Tags: scala, scala-2.13

I have some code:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

trait LogicUnit

trait Ezib extends LogicUnit
trait Zieb extends LogicUnit

object LogicUnit {

    @inline 
    def combine[A <: LogicUnit, B <: LogicUnit](arg1: A, arg2: B): Future[LogicUnit] = {

        if (arg1.isInstanceOf[Ezib] && arg2.isInstanceOf[Ezib]) return Future(new Ezib {})
        else if (arg1.isInstanceOf[Zieb] && arg2.isInstanceOf[Zieb]) return Future(new Zieb {})

        else if (arg1.isInstanceOf[Ezib] && arg2.isInstanceOf[Zieb]) return Future(new Zieb {})
        else return Future(new Ezib {})
    }
}
```

Since this code will be run a lot I am trying to optimize it a lot hence, I am trying to combine the first two lines of the combine function. To do so I figured the code would look something like this:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

trait LogicUnit

trait Ezib extends LogicUnit
trait Zieb extends LogicUnit

object LogicUnit {

    @inline 
    def combine[A <: LogicUnit, B <: LogicUnit](arg1: A, arg2: B): Future[LogicUnit] = {

        if (arg1.isInstanceOf[typeOf(arg2)]) return Future(arg1)

        else if (arg1.isInstanceOf[Ezib] && arg2.isInstanceOf[Zieb]) return Future(new Zieb {})
        else return Future(new Ezib {})
    }

}
```

Is there any way I can get the code to just check if the two types are the same so I don't have to match for all cases?

Comment: _I am trying to optimize it a lot_ I'd recommand avoiding premature optimizations, run your code and if it's slow then investigate on optimizations. From this piece of code I don't expect any significative performance gain by the change you want to do.

Comment: Also, you probably want to remove the `return` from your code (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560463/return-in-scala) and use pattern matching instead of the `isInstanceOf`

Comment: You will almost certainly get a bigger performance speedup in your code by replacing calls to `Future`'s `apply` method with `Future.successful`.

Comment: @Gaël J I believe that pattern matching is converted into reflection anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues here:

It is unlikely that these tests are going to make any difference to the performance because creating and running a `Future` is a much more complex operation and will dominate the time.

The type parameters are unnecessary since the values are always treated as `LogicUnit` so the signature can just be:

```
def combine(arg1: LogicUnit, arg2: LogicUnit): Future[LogicUnit]
```

It is better to use `match` rather than `isInstanceOf` because the compiler then knows what the type of the argument is.

The first version does not depend on the type of `arg1` so there is no need to test it:

```
def combine(arg1: LogicUnit, arg2: LogicUnit): Future[LogicUnit] =
  arg2 match {
    case _: Ezib => Future(new Ezib {})
    case _: Zieb => Future(new Zieb {})
  }
```

If you do need to test both arguments, nest the tests so that the first test is not repeated:

```
def combine(arg1: LogicUnit, arg2: LogicUnit): Future[LogicUnit] =
  arg1 match {
    case a1: Ezib =>
      arg2 match {
        case a2: Ezib => Future(???)
        case a2: Zieb => Future(???)
      }
    case a1: Zieb =>
      arg2 match {
        case a2: Ezib => Future(???)
        case a2: Zieb => Future(???)
      }
  }
```

This formulation is clear and readable, and it allows each branch to use a value of `a1` and `a2` that are known by the compiler to be the specific type that has been matched.

It may also be the case that using polymorphic versions of `combine` would improve performance:

```
def combine(arg1: Ezib, arg2: Ezib): Future[LogicUnit] = ???
def combine(arg1: Ezib, arg2: Zieb): Future[LogicUnit] = ???
def combine(arg1: Zieb, arg2: Ezib): Future[LogicUnit] = ???
def combine(arg1: Zieb, arg2: Zieb): Future[LogicUnit] = ???

def combine(arg1: LogicUnit, arg2: LogicUnit): Future[LogicUnit] =
  arg1 match {
    case a1: Ezib =>
      arg2 match {
        case a2: Ezib => combine(a1, a2)
        case a2: Zieb => combine(a1, a2)
      }
    case a1: Zieb =>
      arg2 match {
        case a2: Ezib => combine(a1, a2)
        case a2: Zieb => combine(a1, a2)
      }
  }
```

If the concrete type is known at the call site then the compiler can call the appropriate method directly rather than having to match the type.

Comment: Thank you. The futures were there because I was going to modify the function to do the operation on massive collections. Regarding the type parameters, I did not want the function to take in just a LogicUnit but only an inherited object.

Comment: @BradOo The `<:` bound does not stop you passing a `LogicUnit` to the method. If you don't want to allow `LogicUnit` args then just stick with the 4 polymorphic versions of `combine`.